# Power Series in a Banach Space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, nonlinear-analysis

I'm looking at differentiability, analyticity and power series functions between Banach spaces, I'm using Soo Bong Chae's book "Holomorphy and Calculus in Normed Spaces".

The book has the definition:

> A power series from $E$ to $F$ about $\xi\in E$ is a formal series of the form $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{A_m (x-\xi)^m}$$ where $A_m \in \mathcal{B}^m(E;F)$.

Here we have the idea of a Taylor series, we have the $m$ derivatives. On page 168, it is said who $A_m$ is,
$$A_m = \frac{1}{m!}d^mf(\xi)$$
where $d^mf$ is the $m$-linear map, $d^mf: U\to \mathcal{B}^n(E,F)$.

So here is my doubt, the power series should be from $E$ to $F$? I'm probably misinterpreting something... should I consider $d^mf$ applied m times to $\xi$? But I didn't get that from the book.

In that case, I would also like to know if anyone has any book references or material that addresses complex analysis in Banach spaces.

Notation: $\mathcal{B}^n(E,F)$ is the space of all continuous multilinear mappings of $E\times\cdots E$ ($n$-times) into $F$.

Comment: $(x - \xi)^m = (x - \xi, \ldots, x - \xi)$ and you are evaluating an $m$-map on an $m$-vector. Thus, $A_m(x - \xi)^m = A_m(x - \xi, \ldots, x - \xi) \in F.$

Comment: @WilliamM. In particular, I'm working with Banach algebras, so I was interpreting with multiplication. That's what I find strange... we don't have that in the usual case, using $\mathbb{C}$, Shouldn't it also be interpreted as an m-tuple? I don't know if you understood my question...

Comment: In the "usual" case, you have the same formula, if $f^{(k)}(z_0)$ is the $k$th derivative of $f,$ then the $k$-linear function is $(t_1, \ldots, t_k) \mapsto f^{(k)}(z_0) t_1 t_2 \cdots t_k,$ where $(t_1, \ldots, t_k) \in \mathbf{C}^k.$ If you evaluate this formula at $(t, \ldots, t) \in \mathbf{C}^k,$ then $t \mapsto f^{(k)}(z_0) t^k$ is the $(k+1)$th term of the power series.

Comment: @WilliamM. thanks for the clarifications. And nice cat in the photo =)